# Iterate a block of HTML, regardless of element type, with Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to iterate a block of HTML with Nokogiri, regardless of what the element type is.

For example, given this variable `html`, passed through Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = "<p>Some text</p><ol><li>List item 1</li><li>List item 2</li></ol><p>Last bit of text</p>"

parsed_html = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

I know I can iterate over each `<p>` by doing:

```
parsed_html.css("p").each do |p|
  puts p
end
```

But again that only grabs all `<p>` tags and not the `<ol>` and its children.

I also know I can grab the `<ol>` by doing:

```
parsed_html.css("p, ol").each do |p|
  puts p
end
```

But **how can I iterate over all the elements regardless of explicitly stating which ones I want to iterate over?**

For example, given another html block:

```
html = "<p>text 1</p><ol><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li></ol><ul><li>item 1</li></ul><h2>header</h2>"
```

How can I return something like:

```
<p>text 1</p>
<ol><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li></ol>
<ul><li>item 1</li></ul>
<h2>header</h2>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CSS accepts wildcards, so you mean like, `parsed_html.css("*").map(&:name)`?

Comment: @Kache close but yeah I know wildcards work but they also return all the child elements (li, etc). I want to be able to iterate over all the first level child elements (p, ol, ul, h2) all at once

Comment: ah, why didn't you say so to start? ok updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CSS child selector](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/):

```
parsed_html.css('body > *')
```

This selects only direct children of the element(s).

```
irb(main):015:0> parsed_html = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
irb(main):016:0> parsed_html.css('body > *')
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3c00 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3bec "text 1">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3c64 name="ol" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3c28 name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3c14 "item 1">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3c50 name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3c3c "item 2">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ca0 name="ul" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3c8c name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3c78 "item 1">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3cc8 name="h2" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3cb4 "header">]>]
irb(main):017:0> parsed_html.css('body > *').map {|e| e.name }
=> ["p", "ol", "ul", "h2"]
```

This works since Nokogiri will create a skeleton when you use Nokogiri::HTML:

```
irb(main):018:0> parsed_html.to_s
=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body>\n<p>text 1</p>\n<ol>\n<li>item 1</li>\n<li>item 2</li>\n</ol>\n<ul><li>item 1</li></ul>\n<h2>header</h2>\n</body></html>\n"
```

You can also just use [Nokogiri::HTML.fragment](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FHTML.fragment) instead of `HTML()`:

```
frag = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)
frag.children.map(&:to_html).join("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just answering the questions you wrote:

**how can I iterate over all the elements**

CSS accepts wildcards, so you can just:

```rb
Nokogiri::HTML(html).css("*").map(&:name)
# => ["html", "body", "p", "ol", "li", "li", "p"]
```

**given "this html" how do I return "something like"**

```rb
html = "<p>text 1</p><ol><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li></ol><ul><li>item 1</li></ul><h2>header</h2>"

puts Nokogiri::HTML(html).css('body').inner_html
# <p>text 1</p>
# <ol>
# <li>item 1</li>
# <li>item 2</li>
# </ol>
# <ul><li>item 1</li></ul>
# <h2>header</h2>
```

**I want to be able to iterate over all the first level child elements (p, ol, ul, h2)**

```rb
Nokogiri::HTML(html).css('body').children.map(&:name)
# => ["p", "ol", "ul", "h2"]
```

Comment: We can extend your code to print out the nested children:

```ruby
Nokogiri::HTML(html).css('body').children.map { |node| "<#{node.name}>#{node.children.to_s}<#{node.name}/>" }
```

Should return: 
```ruby
[
"<p/>text 1<p/>", 
"<ol/><li>item 1</li>\n<li>item 2</li><ol/>", 
"<ul/><li>item 1</li><ul/>", 
"<h2/>header<h2/>"
]
```